# App is not syncing in KFTU cloud Amazon App

Tags: android

I recently submit an updated version of my app to Amazon Store. And then on the App Status they marked several devices to have a problem:

> App is not syncing in KFTU cloud.

I have no idea what "KFTU Cloud" is and couldn't find it on their [developer portal](https://developer.amazon.com/) and google also doesn't help much.

The App itself is LIVE but this kind of error bothers me because the previous version didn't have it. And the changes I made on this version is only a removing some visual assets.

Anyone know what **KFTU Cloud** is?